# ¿Como obtener la fecha de excel con PHPExcel?

Tags: php, date, phpexcel

Cordial Saludo
He creado una clase para realizar cargas masivas con ayuda de PHPExcel, la información a cargar tiene columnas en formato fecha pero me es imposible capturarlas con el PHPExcel, al hacerlo me trae números como si relazara una conversión de alguna manera...

Alguien me podría explicar a que de debe eso? y ¿Hay alguna manera de solucionarlo?

Consulta generada por el PHPExcel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen de la data (Ejemplo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

has intentado:

```
$cell = $excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B' . $i);
$InvDate= $cell->getValue();
if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)) {
     $InvDate = date($format, PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($InvDate)); 
}
```

Ejemplo de Formato:

```
$InvDate = date($format = "Y-m-d", PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($InvDate));
```

tal vez te ayude

Comment: Cordial saludo Francisco, gracias por responder. Esta solución muestra un formato de fecha valido pero la fecha que muestra no es igual a la del archivo.

Comment: cámbiale el formato al que necesites, después de tenerlo a mano eso es lo mas fácil...

Comment: $format = "d-m-Y"

Comment: Listo Francisco el error es minimo, lo que pasaba era que repetias la linea de codigo `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($InvDate)` pero solo utilizando una de ellas funciona correctamente.

Comment: haaa la segunda linea es del ejemplo de formato lo edito y lo separo..

Comment: si te sirve marcala como respuesta. saludos.

Comment: Internamente Excel guarda las fechas y los tiempos como un número (días desde 1/1/1900). Si se quiere averiguar/cambiar cómo aparece la fecha en la hoja de cálculo, habrá que trabajar con el formato de la celda, no con su valor.

Comment: Es correcto francisco muchísimas gracias, fue de gran utilidad

Comment: Ejemplo de la documentación: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#write-a-date-or-time-into-a-cell

Comment: @SJuan76 Gracias por el ejemplo :)

Comment: @SJuan76 lo que agregaste s la manera de colocar la fecha ... la pregunta es obtener... creo que son dos cosas diferente

Answer (score 0):

Por si es de utilidad para alguien dejo el codigo.

```
$fields_table = array(
    "nombre", "apellidos", "fecha_nac"
  );

  //inicializamos sql como un array
  $sql = array();

  //array con las letras de la cabecera de un archivo excel
  $letras = array(
    "A","B","C","D","E","F","G",
    "H","I","J","Q","L","M","N",
    "O","P","Q","R","S","T","U",
    "V","W","X","Y","Z"
  );

  //recorremos el excel y creamos un array para después insertarlo en la base de datos
  for($i = 1;$i <= $rows; $i++)
  {
    //ahora recorremos los campos del formulario para ir creando el array de forma dinámica
    for($z = 0; $z < count($fields_table); $z++)
    {
      $cell = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($letras[$z] . $i);
      $data= $cell->getValue();


      if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)) {
        $data = date($format = "Y-m-d", PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($data)); 

      }

      $sql[$i][trim($fields_table[$z])] = $data;
    }
  }
```

PDT: Muchas gracias Francisco